# Converting String to float in ios

Tags: ios, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios-4.2, ios4

Hello friends I Have a float type variable ,which contains a total price of specific item,so first I have converted into NSString..below is my code

```
float total;

[grandTotal setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:**@"$%.2f"**,total]];
```

so here grandTotal is of type UILabel..where I want the total in the format which I have written in the code

now again when i try to covert to do this

```
float previousTotal = [[grandTotal text] floatValue];
```

I am getting value of previousTotal = zero.

So I think their is issue with $ sign how to solve this is issue..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you can solve it by using

```
float previousTotal = [[[grandTotal text] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"$" withString:@""] floatValue];
```

But I think it is better to pass directly your float value.

Answer (score 0):

I think its better to use

float previousTotal=total;

that is fare and simple.